# Form action without file name

Tags: php, html

could you explain this code?

```
<form method="post" action="/login/">
    <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Name..." required="required">
    <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="***********" required="required">
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Log in">
</form>
```

I know action="login.php" however there is no file in action. How can this work? There is no folder called "login" in root folder.

Comment: maybe there is a **/login/index.php** file?

Comment: @letiagoalves - "There is no folder called "login" in root folder."

Comment: This is pretty much a useless question because there is way too little information. To properly answer this question more information about your server setup would be required.

Answer (score 2):

There are plenty of different ways this *could* work, if we assume Apache then [Alias](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_alias.html) and [mod_rewrite](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html) directives spring to mind as possibilities.

Answer (score 1):

It may be configured in your .htaccess file to handle this url as a file.

Answer (score 1):

Please configure your code in .htaccess

```
RewriteRule  ^login/?$ login.php?param1=$1 [QSA,L]
```